# CPU Throttling on Ubuntu 22.04 (ok on 20.04)

Tags: power-management, temperature, cpu-load, cpufreq, intel-cpu

I've made a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 on Lenovo Yoga X390 (previously using Ubuntu 20.04, which worked satisfactorily for a long time). The hardware configuration didn't change; the CPU is i5-8265U (there is no external GPU in this machine, just integrated Intel).

It was installed and configured with TLP. The laptop works fine but throttles the CPU constantly to 3.7GHz even if the CPU load is 5-20%. That wasn't the case for Ubuntu 20.04, which was scaling down CPU frequency in such cases.

Is there any configuration I'm missing after re-install?

Besides, I can observe that sometimes the CPU slows down to 400MHz when extensively using integrated GPU (i.e. teleconferencing).

I've already checked the https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tlp/+bug/1934944
but that is not the case:

> power-profiles-daemon.service

is not installed in my system.

Any hints and help are highly appreciated; thanks in advance.

Peter
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that your observation of CPU frqeuency throttling to 3.7GHz is due to the number of active cores at the time. The way to know for certain is to read and decode the related MSRs (Machine Specific Registers) manually or to use turbostat (linux tools common package, I think) without the `--quiet` command line option. Example:

```
doug@s15:~$ sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt --interval 15
...
cpu0: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x23242526
35 * 100.0 = 3500.0 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
36 * 100.0 = 3600.0 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
37 * 100.0 = 3700.0 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
38 * 100.0 = 3800.0 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
...
```

Where you can see the maximum turbo frequency is reduced from 3.8GHz to 3.5GHz between 1 and 4 active cores. This is a function of the processor and some BIOS settings and would not be different between 22.04 and 20.04 as you claim. However, sometimes one can adjust the `MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT` MSR. Example:

```
doug@s19:~$ sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 3
...
cpu0: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x303030303030
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 6 active cores
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 5 active cores
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
...
```

Your TDP for your low power mobile processor is low at 15 watts, but is configurable. Your frequency throttling while videoconferencing might be power limit or thermal related. Monitor things with turbostat. Example:

```
doug@s19:~$ sudo turbostat --quiet --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 5
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt
0.01    3816    199     46      2.47    1.82    0.00    1.33
0.01    2897    211     47      2.41    1.75    0.00    1.33
0.00    4230    128     46      2.40    1.74    0.00    1.33
0.19    4713    733     46      2.89    2.23    0.00    1.34
36.95   4758    22942   75      42.58   41.93   0.00    1.34
99.49   4725    60326   74      107.93  107.28  0.00    1.33
99.45   4731    60170   75      108.37  107.71  0.00    1.33
99.40   4746    60517   75      109.30  108.64  0.00    1.33
99.42   4753    60243   75      110.19  109.53  0.00    1.33
99.46   4764    60143   76      111.08  110.42  0.00    1.33
99.56   4781    60165   75      112.55  111.89  0.00    1.33
99.66   4791    60141   75      113.50  112.82  0.00    1.34
99.72   4797    60532   75      113.65  112.99  0.00    1.33
99.76   4800    60126   74      114.09  113.43  0.00    1.33
^C99.76 4800    5598    74      114.13  113.41  0.00    1.34
```

My processor temperature limit is set to 75 degrees C. Observe some slight throttling as the processor temperature goes greater than or equal to 75. My power limit is 125 watts, and it did not get there.

Comment: Thanks. How do I install turbostat? Out of box, there is none, and Linux-tools gives some 165 packages, not sure which one to install.

Comment: either linux-tools-common or linux-laptop-tools-common packages seems to have the turbostat binary.

Comment: Finally, it is in a kernel-specific package (linux-oem-6.5-tools-6.5.0-1014 in my case).